# Coalesced memory access to 2d array with CUDA

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I'm working on a piece of CUDA C++ code and need each thread to, essentially, access a 2D array in global memory by BOTH row-major AND column-major.  Specifically, I need each thread-block to:

- generate it's own 1-d array (let's say, gridDim # of elements)
- Write these to global memory
- Read the n-th element of each written array, where n is block ID.

The way I see it, only the write OR the read can be coalesced, and the other will be accessing a separate cache line for each element (and perform terribly).  I've read that texture memory has a 2-d caching mechanism, but don't know if it can be used to improve this situation.

BTW I am using a GTX 770, so its a GK104 Kepler card with compute capability 3.0.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: There is an option using shared memory, but it is a challenge to implement and isn't suitable for all applications. Could you please say what the method you are working on is?

Comment: I'm working on some research into algorithms on the GPU.  I'm looking at search/sort algorithms and trying to optimize the prefix sum portion currently (to avoid using atomics).  What I'm trying to accomplish is essentially a global memory transpose so that each block gets 1 element from every other block.  This will let me read and write in a coalesced pattern and perform a prefix sum across elements from every block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my algorithm itself had to be re-worked, since there is no way to avoid the performance hit from non-coalesced operations with the above method.  Instead, I was able to merge values on each block and use much less global memory.

As a side note, I did some experimentation with coalesced vs. non-coalesced operations to determine how much slowdown it causes.  It turns out non-coalesced reads are about 10x slower than coalesced, while non-coalesced writes are about 15x slower.  So I guess having non-coalesced reads is the lesser of two evils...

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this it can be worth it to have a transpose operation in between each access pattern to put the data in optimal order. The transpose itself can be written to use SMEM so its reads and writes are coalesced.

See: http://www.nvidia.com/content/nvision2008/tech_presentations/Game_Developer_Track/NVISION08-Image_Processing_and_Video_with_CUDA.pdf

Alternatively (and alluded to by Christian in his comment) if you're able to make your suboptimal pass do something similar to the SMEM transpose as its first steps, you can skip the full transpose and just use its concepts to optimize it.

Comment: I see how transposition can allow intra-block operations to be coalesced, but how about transposing a matrix where each block has 1 row and needs to get 1 column?

Comment: @Nisrak: You don't do it that way: you break the 2D matrix up into NxN submatrices where N is a multiple of 32 (or whatever you need for maximum coalescence), rather than break it up into rows or columns.